# Adblock Changes My Paragraph Position whenever I turn it on or off

Tags: html, css, adblock

How come whenever I turn on or off my adblock my paragraph/text changes positions. When I turn on adblock and the ads are off the paragraph goes all the way at the bottom, and when I turn off adblock where the ads are on the paragraph changes and goes to a place where I want it to be but I want it to stop moving positions whenever I turn on/off adblock I just want it to stay in one place. 
here's my webpage

```css
.Copyright {
  width: 700px;
  height: 177px;
  margin-top: 1895px;
  margin-left: 615px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="icon" href="https://adventureplus.ca/webicon.ico" type="image/icon">
</head>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="aboutstyle.css">
  </div>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="aboutstyle.css">
</head>

<body class="aboutbg">

  <body>
    <div>
      <img src="adventureplusbodypage.jpg" class="bodypage" alt="ed">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="aboutstyle.css">
    </div>
  </body>
  <div class="main">

    <a href="index.html">
      <p align="center"> <img src="new adpluslogo.png" class="Pluslogoon" alt="HTML Tutorial"></a>
    </p>
    <div class="menu">
      <div>
        <img src="new navbar.png" class="nav" alt="nav">
      </div>
      <a href="about.html"><img src="Aboutbar.png" class="Aboutbar" alt="about"></a>
      <a href="ArchiveTwo.html"><img src="Archivebar.png" class="Archivebar" alt="archive"></a>
      <a href="Extras.html"><img src="Extrasbar.png" class="Extrasbar" alt="extras"></a>
      <a href="Characters.html"><img src="Charactersbar.png" class="Charactersbar" alt="characters"></a>
    </div>

    <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="https://disqus.com/?ref_noscript" rel="nofollow">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/js" href="jsabout.js">
</body>

<div>
  <img src="friends, graduations , and begininigs part 86.jpg" class="Part99" alt="img">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Navi.css">
</div>

<div>
  <img src="aboot.jpg" class="Acrbar" alt="img">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Navi.css">
</div>

<head>
  <div>
    <a href="January162020.html" class="Previous">Previous &raquo;</a>
    <a href="January212020.html" class="Next">Next &raquo;</a>
  </div>
</head>

<div>
  <img src="ben banner.jpg" class="bensbanner" alt="mn">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Other.css">
</div>

<div>
  <a href="https://twitter.com/Anonymisartist?lang=en">
    <img src="twitterlogo.png" class="Twat" alt="img">
  </a>
</div>

<div>
  <a href="https://www.deviantart.com/sanrokk?rnrd=258670">
    <img src="deviantartloglo.png" class="deviant" alt="img">
  </a>
</div>

<div>
  <a href="https://instagram.com/anonymisartist/?hl=en">
    <img src="instalogo.png" class="insta" alt="img">
  </a>
</div>

<div>

  <head>
    <div id="disqus_thread" style="height: 538px; width: 1200px; margin-left: -415px; margin-top: -247px">

      <script>
        var disqus_config = function() {
          this.page.url = 'https://adventureplus.ca/January202020.html';
          this.page.identifier = 'January202020.html';
        };
        (function() {
          var d = document,
            s = d.createElement('script');

          s.src = 'https://adventureplus-ca.disqus.com/embed.js';

          s.setAttribute('data-timestamp', +new Date());
          (d.head || d.body).appendChild(s);
        })();
      </script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Navi.css">
      </ul>
      <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="https://disqus.com/?ref_noscript" rel="nofollow">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</head>


</script>
<div>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Other.css">
  <div class="Commentary">
    <h1>Hi Guys</h1>

    <p>Welcome to my site. This is where I will be posting lots of ADplus content and plus more juicy stories. Just sit back and relax and enjoy the fun "adventures" of this webcomic has to offer. The comic updates every weekdays. Stay tuned for more updates
      soon to come :).</p>
  </div>

  <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="https://disqus.com/?ref_noscript" rel="nofollow">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/js" href="jsabout.js">
  </body>










</div>
</head>





<div>
  <img src="placeholder.jpg" alt="img" class="adone">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="aboutstyle.css">
</div>



<div>
  <img src="adtwo.jpg" class="adstwo" alt="i">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="aboutstyle.css">
</div>








</div>

<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    .adslot_1 {
      max-width: 190px;
      max-height: 772px;
    }
    
    @media (min-width:193px) {
      .adslot_1 {
        width: 193px;
        height: 770px;
      }
    }
    
    @media (min-width:193px) {
      .adslot_1 {
        width: 193px;
        height: 770px;
      }
    }
  </style>
  <ins class="adsbygoogle adslot_1" style="display: block; position:relative;margin-top: -1469px; margin-left: 315px; width: 160px; max-height: 600px;" data-ad-client="ca-pub-9710909156400610" data-ad-slot="5003175748"></ins>
  <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
  <script>
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
  </script>

  <script>
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
  </script>
  </div>
</head>


<body>
  <style type="text/css">
    .adslot_2 {
      max-width: 728px;
      max-height: 93px;
    }
    
    @media (min-width:728px) {
      .adslot_2 {
        width: 728px;
        height: 93px;
      }
    }
    
    @media (min-width:728px) {
      .adslot_2 {
        width: 728px;
        height: 93px;
      }
    }
  </style>
  <ins class="adsbygoogle adslot_2" style="display: block; position: relative; margin-top: -869px; margin-left: 725px; width: 728px; height: 93px;" data-ad-client="ca-pub-9710909156400610" data-ad-slot="5873404284"></ins>
  <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
  <script>
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
  </script>

  <script>
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
  </script>
  </div>
</body>



<div>

  <head>
    <div>

      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Other.css">
      <div class="Copyright">

        <p>&copy;&nbsp;2019&ndash;2020 AdventurePlus Comics Created By Nathaniel Enriquez</p>
      </div>

  </head>
  </div>


</html>
```

output:

[Image of Adblock On](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1Rnq.jpg)

[Image of  Adblock Off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4LFi.jpg)

[Image of  Adblock On](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbpzx.jpg)

Comment: Why do you have multiple `head` and `body` tags? It must be one of each per document. To be honest, you have so many errors with your HTML, that is hard to point a solution, use an [online tool](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) to verify your code

Comment: I would merge the two head tags and two body tags, just like @CalvinNunes said.